# Product of two continuous functions

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces, and let $Y$ be a group equipped with multiplication.

Assume we have two continuous functions $f$ and $g$ whose domain and codomain are $X$ and $Y$, respectively. What general conditions on $X$ and $Y$ garantees that the function defined by the product of $f$ and $g$ and having the same domain and codomain is continuous?

Comment: For example you can ask the multiplication map $\mu : Y\times Y \rightarrow Y$, $\mu(a,b)=a\cdot b$ be continuous, but maybe I didn't understand your question

Comment: You're right, but what extra structure(conditions) on Y guarnatee that this map is continuous?

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_group